# how to filter out a ndarray given a specific letter?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a `ndarray (y)` including the existing labels. These labels are in binary 0 or 1.
I have a second `ndarray  (X)` representing the training set.

How can extract from `X` and `y` all the data corresponding to label 0. So, the new data will be:
the original data: `X, y`
and another extracted `X1` with its corresponding `y1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
X1, y1 = X[y==0], y[y==0]
```

Comment: Thanks, does that preserve the order?

Comment: Yes, the filtered values will be in the same order as in the original.